# Algo for narrowing cavern

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation

I'm in a bit of crunch time and I find myself spending way too much time tinkering with an algo, so I would like some help.

In the game I am working on, there are some old-style, pixelated minigames. One of the minigame is a spaceship in a cavern. The caverns curves and narrows down over time until the ship crashes in a wall. I want them to be generated at random during runtime.

I'm having a problem creating the walls of the cavern and narrowing them while keeping a smooth curve on them.

For the narrowing, I keep track of it with a variable that decreases over time, but how about the curving and how to keep it natural? I've though of a keeping a target point that goes up and down randomly and have the wall try to reach for it, therefore smoothing the randomized number but it is not working great.

Any ideas/algo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track, add noise (perlin or otherwise..) to the floor and ceiling to make it look 'natural' and jagged. Then you could use 1D [Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), as you suggested actually, as a target point, and draw the opening around that point.

Generate the level one slice at a time, and simply move that slice toward the player. If it goes up and down too fast (the target value, that is), you can try and smooth it using a sliding window, the simplest being simply averaging with the previous target value like so

```
window = 0.8;
targetY = next_brownian_value() * (1-window) + targetY * window;
```

Which will create an exponential sliding window (in this case, the targetY will be one fifth the new random value, 4/25ths of the previous random value, 16/125ths of the one before that, etc). Try playing with the window size and see what happens, higher value gives more smoothing (higher influence of previous values).

Note that the `next_brownian_value` should not be influenced by the targetY, it should go on its usual drunken walk.

**EDIT**
Naming the weighting factor 'window' was a slight misnomer, as a larger window should have a more smoothing effect. I've reversed the meaning above to make it more intuitive. It's still not really a window 'size' in a theoretical sense (which is usually defined to where the contribution is 1/e for exponential stuff..), but it least it's the right way around now..

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is definitely the way I should do it. But I can't find an implementation of brownian motion (in java). In the end, I'm going with a random point selection for the target. Far from perfect, but at least it's got the 'old school' part going for it.

Comment: @ADB; [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) is a simplified brownian motion, and should suffice, and is more or less simply `x = x + random();` where `random()` is -1 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

You could use one-dimensional Perlin noise to generate the floor and ceiling, and weight the values so they get closer together towards the right side of the level.